# How to enable OpenSSL for PHP Cli?

Tags: command-line, php, openssl, php-cli

There is no major difference in the `php.ini` files located at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. But  `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` when accessed from a browser says **OpenSSL support enabled** whereas `php -info | grep openssl` executed in a terminal gives  `OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)`.

I have the latest versions of `libssl-dev` and `openssl` installed. How to enable OpenSSL for cli version?

Comment: Is there a GUI version of PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Same trouble for me. After spending some hours searching for a solution I find out that the command `php` is associated with an old version of php as against of the `php5` command on my development mashine:

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.18 (cli) (built: Nov 20 2012 19:34:35)

php5 -v
PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:24:35)
```

So I reinstalled composer with the following command and now it works for me:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php5
```

Best regards!

Comment: `sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php5` did not work for me. I had to recompile php from source with openssl to make composer work.

Comment: There's no need to run ```curl``` via sudo. And running random scripts from the internet is also considered [dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29382739 "why using curl | sudo sh is not advised?") and should not be recommended lightly.